# powershell get-date to log file

Tags: powershell, output, logfile, getdate

I'm trying to get a script to test connectivity of a list of IP addresses and log the output to a file. I would like it to put a time/date stamp in the log when when I get no response. I'd like to execute the script over a 2-3 day period. I've got it to put the time/date stamp on the output of the console but not in the output file. Here's the script.

```
$names=Get-Content "C:\script\hname.txt"
foreach($name in $names){
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
        Write-Host "$name is up" -ForegroundColor Green
        $output+="$name is up,"
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "$name is down" -ForegroundColor Red
        Get-Date 
        $output+="$name is down,"
        " "
    }
}
$output | Out-File -FilePath "C:\script\results.txt"
Start-Sleep -s 3
```

this is the results on the ps console

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Users\admin\Documents\Test Connection-3sec.ps1
192.168.1.254 is up
192.168.1.74 is down

Tuesday, October 10, 2023 12:06:05 PM
 
192.168.1.239 is up
192.168.1.23 is down
Tuesday, October 10, 2023 12:06:07 PM
 
192.168.1.189 is up
192.168.1.78 is up
192.168.1.79 is up
192.168.1.81 is up
192.168.1.89 is down
Tuesday, October 10, 2023 12:06:08 PM
 
192.168.1.82 is up
192.168.1.85 is up
192.168.1.45 is down
Tuesday, October 10, 2023 12:06:10 PM

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

But this is what I get in the results.txt file.

```
192.168.1.254 is up,
192.168.1.74 is down,
192.168.1.239 is up,
192.168.1.23 is down,
192.168.1.189 is up,
192.168.1.78 is up,
192.168.1.79 is up,
192.168.1.81 is up,
192.168.1.89 is down,
192.168.1.82 is up,
192.168.1.85 is up,
192.168.1.45 is down,
```

as a side note the format doesn't have the new line feed which I understand I should be able to get if I add `` $output+="$name is up," +"`n`r" ``

I've tried putting the get-date at the end of the $output line, to no avail.

```
$output+="$name is down," Get-Date
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To match the console output:

```
$output+="$name is down,`n$(Get-date)`n"
```

But personally I'd simplify it and keep the date on the same line

```
$output+="$name is down. $(Get-date)"
```

And of course you could always add it to `$output` as its own entry:

```
$output+="$name is down, "
$output+= Get-date
```

Comment: all work well, thanks for the info.
One more question, how do I make the script run in a loop for 3 days?

Comment: @txjastx _Don't do that._ Long-running tasks can run into trouble like memory leaks, unexpected CPU use, or hanging and silently failing to continue. Instead, create a scheduled task to run periodically. This allows the process to end and return memory or other resources, and will keep waking up and running even if an individual instance has trouble.

Comment: I'll check into the scheduled task, I'm trying to catch an intermittent problem and figured it may take some time to do so. Thanks again for the info

Comment: so the schedule task is not working well for me. I created one in the action tab I have start a program,

Comment: so the schedule task is not working well for me. I created one in the action tab I have start a program, with powershell.exe in the Program/Script field. for the add arguments I have -File "C:\script\TestConn.ps1"

Comment: dont use `-file`. Just have the file name. So the result is "powershell.exe C:\script\testconn.ps1`. Also remember the scheduled task may run in a different execution context (as a different user account, without things liked mapped drives).

Comment: I removed -file but still no action. I see the ps window pop up and disappear. I don't see any text in the ps window.

Comment: With a scheduled task, you shouldn't see anything at all. It should run in the background, and you would monitor the log file.

Comment: task scheduler is treating 2 different tasks differently. - only difference one script runs in a loop for 10 min. the run button in task scheduler one opens a ps window and runs the script, then closes the window - file is written as expected. The second task does nada. I open  ps ise window and execute both the scripts they both execute and write the output file as expected.  your previous comments task scheduler shouldn't open a window when run, but it does on one and successfully writes the output file. the other doesn't even appear to run. What could be causing the inconsistent behavior